# Why gamma-correction is applied to RGB instead of YUV or similar?

Tags: graphics, colors, computer-vision

As far as I understand, gamma-correction is applied to adjust high range of luminance in real world to relatively low range of luminance in displays.
And if it's goal is to adjust luminance, why it is applied to all of the RGB channels independently?

In most popular color models which include luminocity (like YUV) the luminocity term itself is computed with different coefficients for RGB channels. So why gamma coefficient is the same for all RGB colors? And why it would not be logical to apply this coefficient to luminocity term only and remain color space untouched (UV terms in case of YUV model)?

Is this connected somehow with the fact that there are three types of cones in human eye which more or less correspond to RGB colors?
But even if cone cells adapt independently from each other, the light intensity for all of them should be uniformly adjusted by the work of lens and pupil.

Comment: @kel solaar had the best answer so I won't repeat, but just to nit-pick, please don't use the term "luminosity" when discussing gamma encoded video Y ′ . The correct term is "luma." 

Luminance is linear (no curve, gamma 1.0) as is light in the real world. Luminosity is energy emitted per unit of time. Neither term should be used when discussing gamma encoded images. [See the Gamma FAQ.](https://poynton.ca/notes/colour_and_gamma/GammaFAQ.html)

Answer (score 1):

Gamma correction purpose is not to bring relative Luminance down but to encode values in a perceptual uniform way which will optimise code allocation and thus reduce quantization artefacts compared to a linear encoding of those same values.

As a matter of fact most opto-electronic transfer function (OETF / OECF) and electro-optical transfer function (EOTF / EOCF) such as sRGB, [BT.709](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bt/R-REC-BT.709-6-201506-I!!PDF-E.pdf), [BT.1886](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bt/R-REC-BT.1886-0-201103-I!!PDF-E.pdf) which are power function based (gamma) don't affect the black and white levels.

A combination of different exponents at the display chain / system input and output will result in an end-to-end system gamma that might increase or decrease visual contrast depending the suited result (this is called Picture Rendering). For example, HDTV broadcasting is usually using BT.709 (gamma ±0.5) as the encoding function for the source data (like filming with an HDTV camera) and is decoded by your TV using BT.1886 (gamma 2.4) which yields an end-to-end system gamma of ±1.2, suitable for dim viewing conditions.

In the [Y'UV colourspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV), (notice that I put a prime on Y), Y' doesn't represent *relative Luminance* but *luma*, which is a non linear component: it is already encoded through mean of an OETF (i.e. a gamma encoding function in that case). Similarly the U and V components are non-linear as they are formed from already non linear R'G'B' components.

The computation of *luma* is indeed closely related to the human visual system sensitivity as you can see from the weighting factors used:
`Y' = 0.299 * R' + 0.587 * G' + 0.114*B'`.

I would highly suggest that you take a look at Charles Poynton's [Gamma Faq](http://www.poynton.com/notes/colour_and_gamma/GammaFAQ.html).

I would also recommend that you drop an eye on our [The Importance of Terminology and sRGB Uncertainty slides](http://www.slideshare.net/thomasmansencal/the-importance-of-terminology-and-srgb-uncertainty-notes), they should put you on track with proper terminology and introduce important concepts.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, gamma correction was introduced to cope with the non-linearity of cathode-ray tubes used in television, as there isn't a strict proportionality between the applied tension and the emitted luminance.

At the time, engineers found it more economical to introduce a correction at the broadcast site instead of in every receiver. This is why the correction is in fact a "pre-compensation" and the transmitted images are distorted.

Even though nowadays the technologies in use are completely different, backward compatibility was kept, by inertia and other opportunistic reasons. And the presence / absence of pre-compensation / gamma enforcement in the worlds of digital cameras / color image processing / display screens is a complete mess.

Comment: Actually, gamma is important still today to make the best use of code values, encoding image data in a manner close to human perception which is non-linear. Further, it wasn't just economics to add the gamma curve "prior to transmission," gamma encoding happens at the camera and helps to reduce the perception of noise in the signal.

Comment: As for "complete mess," gamma standards are well defined. sRGB is the standard for the web, and Rec709 is the standard for HDTV, among others. These standards are all available as ICC profiles. HOWEVER, the display gamma can and should be adjusted to compensate for the AMBIENT LIGHTING, as ambient affects perceptual intent.

See [Poynton's Gamma FAQ](https://poynton.ca/notes/colour_and_gamma/GammaFAQ.html)  for an understanding of gamma.